# using asp.net membership database with my own database

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

My plan is such as following:

I have the Asp.Net membership database that keeps info about users.
I want to create my own database in which some of the tables will have fields like userId as a foreign key to primary key field in the membership table Users. So how would I achieve this and what is the best practice for this? Or should I get the value of the user during run time, and then copy that value to my table without the need of any foreign key relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add tables to the existing database, and reference the pk from the Users table as needed. There's no need to use a separate database as long as it's all logically the same application.